# Unable to load tensorflow in Django

Tags: python, django, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a application using tensorflow, but when I include the tensorflow in django and try to start the development server, I got error as below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 98, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 105, in run
    autoreload.main(self.inner_run, None, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 317, in main
    python_reloader(wrapped_main_func, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 296, in python_reloader
    reloader_thread()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 274, in reloader_thread
    change = fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 203, in code_changed
    for filename in gen_filenames():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 101, in gen_filenames
    [filename.__file__ for filename in new_modules
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 102, in <listcomp>
    if hasattr(filename, '__file__')])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.keras'
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

However I am able to import the from tensorflow import keras in python interpreter,  I'm running on python3.7, tensorflow=2.1.0, Django=2.0.7

Comment: __"No module named 'tensorflow_core.keras"__ - can you also add your python file?

Comment: Please, provide code which imports / uses tensorflow and related libs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, from the console, i was guessing there is an issue when Django does a auto reload.
Auto reload will generally happen when any change is detected.
I just upgraded my Django version from 2.X to 3.x and this solved my issue.